# RichResponse VS basicCard order

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

I'm facing a quite annoying issue with the Actions On Google SDK.

I want to send to the user these things in this order :

1. A basic card
2. A text
3. A suggestion chip

I simply did this :

```
let richResponse = assistant.buildRichResponse();
richResponse.addBasicCard( ... );
richResponse.addSimpleResponse( ... );
richResponse.addSuggestions( ... );
```

Problem is, no matter the order set in my code, google will always send the simple response before the card.

If i log the JSON before sending it, the card is indeed AFTER the message.
I tried to simply switch them in the JSON before sending it but then the assistant simply crashes.

All in all, i see no option to achieve what i want :/

If i could send a 1 item carousel i wouldn't need all that, but it's apparently impossible to send such carousel because the assistant also crashes.
If i could add buttons with JSON payload instead of external URL in BasicCard i could also workaround all these issues, but that's not possible either... I feel quite stuck.

Anyone has a workaround ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RichResponse](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#RichResponse) object requires that the first item in the response be a SimpleResponse object, so you need some text first.

However, you are allowed to have two SimpleResponse objects, so you can try adding a SimpleResponse, the card, another SimpleResponse, and then the suggestions.

It isn't clear how being able to have just one option would let you work around this (although I agree). You would still need a SimpleResponse that appears before the option.

It isn't clear what you mean by "buttons with JSON". In this sense, suggestion chips work exactly the same way options do - they send something back to your webhook (options send the tag, while the suggestion chips send their contents).

Comment: Oh ok that makes sens ! Solves my problem thank you !
By "JSON payload" i mean something like facebook. Being able to trigger an action when the button is clicked. A bit like the "key" of carousel cards. When card is clicked, its "key" is sent to the webhook (well..not in most cases because it's buggy but you get the idea ^^)
Suggestion chips only acts as if the user wrote the text, we cannot pass "hidden" data to the server :/

Comment: But you can't pass "hidden" data if the user says anything, either. Remember - focus on voice interactions. What hidden data do you want/need to send?